# How to set the focus to the last item in ui:repeat JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, composite-component

I have a scrollable div and I like to set the focus at the last element. How can I achieve this?

```
<div class="scrolldiv">  
<h:form id="form">  
  <ui:repeat...> 
    <h:panelGrid columns="2"...>  
      <h:graphicImage../>  
      <h:outputText.../>  
    </h:panelGrid>  
  </ui:repeat>  
</h:form>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<ui:repeat var="..." value="..." varStatus="status">
```

you can use status plus property name like `#{status.last}` 
from this properties :

- **begin** of type Integer
- **end** of type Integer
- **index** of type int
- **step** of type Integer
- **even** of type boolean
- **odd** of type boolean
- **first** of type boolean
- **last** of type boolean